# Text-overflow clipping border radius

Tags: css

I'm trying achieve a table where the contents of the tds have `text-overflow: ellipsis`, however the clipping usually occurs where there is a link with twitter bootstraps `label` class (giving it a border radius).

[image: Text-overflow clipping border radius]

As you can see, it clips the border radius giving it a flat end. Each TD needs to be a single row of text, which is why I've used `white-space: nowrap`. Is there any way that I can have the rounded edge on the label if it clips at that point?

Heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cuJ83/13/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a satisfactory result. I needed a combination of applying the text-overflow to the `a` label, with max-width. Then I just needed to add padding to the container or to the `td` to bring it all in bounds.

```
.label {
    border-radius: 1em;
    color: #000;
    background: #ccc;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
table { table-layout: fixed; width: 100% }
table td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cuJ83/21/)</kbd>

The only caveat is it won't handle the overflow on text *after* the label. I'm not resigned to that being impossible but haven't worked it out yet and for my use-case it's not applicable.

Answer (score 3):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuJ83/15/)

You want to apply the rule on the `a.label` and not the parent `td`. The below should do it:

```
td > a.label{
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: I'll update the question but I should have mentioned that I need each TD to be one row of text only.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't apply `text-overflow: ellipsis` to inline elements -so you wont be able to accomplish this using HTML/CSS in the way you currently have lain out

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more please? I'm trying to apply text-overflow to the `td`, which I believe is a block level element?

Comment: `text-overflow` applies to the text content of the `td` only, and not any child elements and their text content, of which the `a` is one

Comment: but in my example you can see that it is applying to the `a`?

Comment: Afraid not- `overflow` is being applied to the `a` as it is content of `td`, `text-overflow` is not, which is why you see the cutoff but not the ellipses- the `a` is extending outside the `td`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50800/discussion-between-mike-campbell-and-sw4)

Answer (score 2):

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuJ83/23/)**</kbd>

#### CSS

```
.thin {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px
}
.label {
    border-radius: 1em;
    color: #000;
    background: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%
}
table td {
    padding-right: 30px;    
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: I think the OP also wants to keep the **ellipsis**, otherwise we can't know if there are more messages or not.

Comment: thank you! for my similar layout 'max-width: 100%' on a label was a cure https://jsfiddle.net/Kitana/mde1sc54/16/